# How to have the dash before the + and - Node expand and collapse in the tree table javascript library

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to have the + - (node collapse and expand) also draw a connecting dash to the tree just like other non branch nodes.

Following is the library
https://www.jqueryscript.net/table/hierarchical-tree-table-view.html

The following span element isn't drawing the - (dash) connecting line if the next element is a node expand

```
<span class="tree-table-space-block" data-part-level="1_3" data-all-level="1_3" data-level="1"><i></i></span>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library you are using is pretty dirty... In order not to change its code, apply css not to `.btn-toggle` itself (because they will already offer `:before` and `:after`), but to their sibling `.tree-table-td-content`.
I would do something like this:

```js
var items = [
        {
            id: 1,
            priority: 1,
            from: 'reacttreetable@simple.com',
            subject: 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing',
            sentDate: '01/01/2019'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            priority: 2,
            from: 'reacttreetable@simple.com',
            subject: 'It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted',
            sentDate: '01/01/2019',
            parentId: 1
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            priority: 3,
            from: 'reacttreetable@simple.com',
            subject: 'It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted',
            sentDate: '01/01/2019',
            parentId: 1
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            priority: 4,
            from: 'reacttreetable@simple.com',
            subject: 'It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted',
            sentDate: '01/01/2019',
            parentId: 3
        },
        {
            id: 5,
            priority: 5,
            from: 'reacttreetable@simple.com',
            subject: 'It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted',
            sentDate: '01/01/2019'
        },
        {
            id: 6,
            priority: 6,
            from: 'reacttreetable@simple.com',
            subject: 'It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted',
            sentDate: '01/01/2019'
        },
        {
            id: 7,
            priority: 7,
            from: 'reacttreetable@simple.com',
            subject: 'It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted',
            sentDate: '01/01/2019',
            parentId: 3
        },
        {
            id: 8,
            priority: 8,
            from: 'reacttreetable@simple.com',
            subject: 'It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted',
            sentDate: '01/01/2019',
            parentId: 3
        },
        {
            id: 9,
            priority: 9,
            from: 'reacttreetable@simple.com',
            subject: 'It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted',
            sentDate: '01/01/2019',
            parentId: 3
        },
        {
            id: 10,
            priority: 10,
            from: 'reacttreetable@simple.com',
            subject: 'It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted',
            sentDate: '01/01/2019',
            parentId: 8
        },
        {
            id: 11,
            priority: 11,
            from: 'reacttreetable@simple.com',
            subject: 'It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted',
            sentDate: '01/01/2019',
            parentId: 8
        },
        {
            id: 12,
            priority: 12,
            from: 'reacttreetable@simple.com',
            subject: 'It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted',
            sentDate: '01/01/2019',
            parentId: 10
        },
        {
            id: 13,
            priority: 13,
            from: 'reacttreetable@simple.com',
            subject: 'It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted',
            sentDate: '01/01/2019',
            parentId: 5
        },
        {
            id: 17,
            priority: 13,
            from: 'reacttreetable@simple.com',
            subject: 'It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted',
            sentDate: '01/01/2019',
            parentId: 13
        },
        {
            id: 18,
            priority: 13,
            from: 'reacttreetable@simple.com',
            subject: 'It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted',
            sentDate: '01/01/2019',
            parentId: 13
        },
        {
            id: 19,
            priority: 13,
            from: 'reacttreetable@simple.com',
            subject: 'It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted',
            sentDate: '01/01/2019',
            parentId: 13
        },
        {
            id: 14,
            priority: 14,
            from: 'reacttreetable@simple.com',
            subject: 'It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted',
            sentDate: '01/01/2019',
            parentId: 5
        },
        {
            id: 15,
            priority: 14,
            from: 'reacttreetable@simple.com',
            subject: 'It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted',
            sentDate: '01/01/2019',
            parentId: 5
        },{
            id: 16,
            priority: 14,
            from: 'reacttreetable@simple.com',
            subject: 'It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted',
            sentDate: '01/01/2019',
            parentId: 5
        }];

(function ($) {
    function flatListToTree(items) {
        const getChild = (item, level, allLevel) => {
            return items.filter(v => v.parentId === item.id)
                .map(v => {
                        const temp = {
                            ...v,
                            level,
                            children: getChild(v, level + 1, level === 0 ? v.id : `${allLevel}_${v.id}`),
                            partLevel: level === 0 ? v.id : `${v.parentId}_${v.id}`,
                            ...(level === 0 ? {
                                allLevel: v.id
                            } : {
                                allLevel: [allLevel, v.id].join('_')
                            }),
                        };
                        return [temp].concat(...temp.children);
                    }
                );
        };

        return [].concat(...getChild({ id: undefined }, 0, undefined))
    };

    $(document.body).delegate('.expand', 'click', function () {
        var level = $(this).attr('data-level');
        var partLevel = $(this).attr('data-part-level');
        var allLevel = $(this).attr('data-all-level');
        var isOpen = $(this).attr('data-is-open');
        var trsDiv = $('.tree-table').find('tbody tr');
        var trsArray = $(trsDiv);
        if (isOpen === '1') {
            for(var i = 0;i < trsArray.length - 1; i++) {
                var tempTr = $(trsArray[i]);
                var trLevel = tempTr.attr('data-level');
                var trPartLevel = tempTr.attr('data-part-level');
                var trAllLevel = tempTr.attr('data-all-level');
                var contain = trAllLevel.split('_')[Number(level)]; // ???????tr?all_level???????id
                var curr = partLevel.split('_'); // ???????part_level??????????????id
                // ??????,
                if (contain && contain === curr[curr.length - 1] && partLevel !== trPartLevel) {
                    tempTr.removeClass('show');
                    tempTr.addClass('hidden');
                }
            }
            $(this).text('+');
            $(this).attr('data-is-open', '0');
        } else {
            for(var i = 0;i < trsArray.length - 1; i++) {
                var tempTr = $(trsArray[i]);
                var trLevel = tempTr.attr('data-level');
                var trPartLevel = tempTr.attr('data-part-level');
                var trAllLevel = tempTr.attr('data-all-level');
                var contain = trAllLevel.split('_')[Number(level)]; // ???????tr?all_level???????id
                var curr = partLevel.split('_'); // ???????part_level??????????????id
                // ??????,
                if (contain && contain === curr[curr.length - 1] && Number(trLevel) > (Number(level))) {
                    var span = $(tempTr.children()[0].children[Number(trLevel)]);
                    var isOpen = $(span).attr('data-is-open');
                    var childrenCount = $(span).attr('data-count');
                    tempTr.removeClass('hidden');
                    tempTr.addClass('show');
                    // pLevel != -1 ?????????,??pLevel?????,???????????
                    if (isOpen && isOpen === '0' && Number(childrenCount) > 0) { // ??????
                        i = i + Number(childrenCount);
                    } else {
                      if (isOpen === '1') {
                        $(span).attr('data-is-open', '1');
                        $(span).text('-');
                        tempTr.removeClass('hidden');
                        tempTr.addClass('show');
                      }
                    }
                }
            }
            $(this).text('-');
            $(this).attr('data-is-open', '1');
        }
    });

    function countChildren(node) {
        var sum = 0,
          children = node && node.length ? node : node.children,
          i = children && children.length;

        if (!i) {
            sum = 0;
        } else {
            while (--i >= 0) {
                if (node && node.length) {
                    sum++;
                    countChildren(children[i]);
                } else {
                    sum += countChildren(children[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }

    function createRows() {
        var fragments = document.createDocumentFragment();
        var opts = flatListToTree(items);
        for (var i = 0; i < opts.length; i++) {
            var item = opts[i];
            var trEle = document.createElement('tr');
            $(trEle).attr('data-part-level', item.partLevel);
            $(trEle).attr('data-all-level', item.allLevel);
            $(trEle).attr('data-level', item.level);
            $(trEle).attr('data-count', countChildren(item));
            var tdEle1 = document.createElement('td');
            for (var j =0; j <= item.level; j++) {
                var spanEle = document.createElement('span');
                $(spanEle).addClass('tree-table-space-block');
                $(spanEle).attr('data-part-level', item.partLevel);
                $(spanEle).attr('data-all-level', item.allLevel);
                $(spanEle).attr('data-level', item.level);
                var iEle = document.createElement('i');
                if (j === item.level) {
                    if (item.children && item.children.length > 0) {
                        $(spanEle).addClass('btn-toggle expand');
                        $(spanEle).attr('data-is-open', '1');
                        $(spanEle).attr('data-count', countChildren(item));
                        $(spanEle).text('-');
                    } else {
                        $(spanEle).addClass('last-block');
                        $(spanEle).append(iEle);
                    }
                } else {
                    $(spanEle).append(iEle);
                }
                $(tdEle1).append(spanEle);
            }

            var spanEle2 = document.createElement('span');
            $(spanEle2).addClass('tree-table-td-content');
            $(spanEle2).text(item.id);
            $(tdEle1).append(spanEle2);

            var tdEle2 = document.createElement('td');
            $(tdEle2).css('width', '200px');
            var spanTd2 = document.createElement('span');
            $(spanTd2).addClass('tree-table-td-content');
            $(spanTd2).text(item.from);
            $(tdEle2).append(spanTd2);

            var tdEle3 = document.createElement('td');
            $(tdEle3).css('width', '200px');
            var spanTd3 = document.createElement('span');
            $(spanTd3).addClass('tree-table-td-content');
            $(spanTd3).text(item.subject);
            $(tdEle3).append(spanTd3);

            var tdEle4 = document.createElement('td');
            $(tdEle4).css('width', '200px');
            var spanTd4 = document.createElement('span');
            $(spanTd4).addClass('tree-table-td-content');
            $(spanTd4).text(item.sentDate);
            $(tdEle4).append(spanTd4);

            var tdEle5 = document.createElement('td');
            $(tdEle5).css('width', '200px');
            var spanTd5 = document.createElement('span');
            $(spanTd5).addClass('tree-table-td-content');
            $(spanTd5).text(item.from);
            $(tdEle5).append(spanTd5);

            $(trEle).append(tdEle1);
            $(trEle).append(tdEle2);
            $(trEle).append(tdEle3);
            $(trEle).append(tdEle4);
            $(trEle).append(tdEle5);
            $(fragments).append(trEle);
        }
        $('#table-tree').append(fragments);
    }
    createRows();
})($);
```

```css
/* solution */

.tree-table-td-content {
  position: relative;
}
.btn-toggle:not([data-level="0"]) + .tree-table-td-content:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: calc(100% + 11px);
  width: 21px;
  top: 16px;
  border-top: solid 1px #d9d9d9;
  pointer-events: none;
}

/* end solution */

.tree-table-wrap {
  width: 100%;
}

.tree-table {
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.tree-table th {
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background: #fafafa;
  font-size: 13px;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
}
.tree-table td {
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #333;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.tree-table tr td:first-child {
  overflow: initial;
}
.tree-table-space-block {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 19px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 7px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.tree-table tr td .tree-table-space-block:first-child {
  margin-left: 7px;
}
.tree-table-space-block.btn-toggle {
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  z-index: 12;
}
.tree-table-space-block.btn-toggle.is-close {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.tree-table-space-block:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 1px;
  height: 36px;
  background: #d9d9d9;
  left: 50%;
  top: -27px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.tree-table-space-block i {
  display: block;
  width: 3px;
  height: 3px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  background: #d9d9d9;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.tree-table-space-block.btn-toggle:before {
  display: none;
}
.tree-table-space-block.last-block:before {
  display: none;
}

.tree-table-space-block.last-block:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #d9d9d9;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -1px;
  left: -10px;
}
.tree-table-space-block.btn-toggle:after {
  display: none;
}
.tree-table tr td .tree-table-space-block:first-child:after {
  display: none;
}

.tree-table-td-content {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 7px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.show {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tree-table-wrap">
  <table class="tree-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
        <th>Column 3</th>
        <th>Column 4</th>
        <th>Column 5</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="table-tree">
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Sir, thanks a lot for the great help. I am highly thankful to you. Many many thanks. 
The + node still doesn't draw the connecting dash. How to have the + node draw the dash as well just like the - node. Kindly help. Thanks once again.

Comment: Many Many thanks sir. Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: I was happy to help. If the answer solves your problem, you can accept it.